# Creating SVG elements without rendering them

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How can I create a function that returns a custom SVG graphic without appending it to anything? Can I create an empty selection and return that?
What I currently have:

```
function makeGraphic(svgParent) {
    return svgParent.append('circle').attrs({...});
}
```

This is what I want:

```
function makeGraphic() {
    return d3.makeCircle?.attrs({...});
}

svgParent.append(makeGraphic());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a temporary svg node with svg namespace inside the function - without rendering the svg. Then you can treat the svg as a typical node while  you manipulate it and return some sort of shape.

One thing to note is that `.append()` accepts a tag name or a function, so I provide the function not its result below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height",200)
  .attr("transform", "translate(200,100)");
  
var makeCircle = function() {
  // create a temporary svg
  let svg = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, "svg")
  // create a circle
  let circle = d3.select(svg).append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");
    
  // return a circle
  return circle.node(); 

}

svg.append(makeCircle);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

With that you could make a more complicated shape generator to return shapes for use with things like `d3.append()`:

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200);
    

var shapes = [{shape: "circle",y: 40, fill: "darkblue"},{shape:"square", y: 35},{y:40}]

svg.selectAll()
  .data(shapes)
  .enter()
  .append(shapemaker);    

function shapemaker(options = {}) {
  let svg = document.createElementNS(d3.namespaces.svg, "svg")
  var shape;
  if (options.shape == "circle") {
    shape = d3.select(svg).append("circle")
       .attr("cx", options.x ? options.x : 50)
       .attr("cy", options.y ? options.y : 50) 
       .attr("r", options.r ? options.r : 10)
       .attr("fill", options.fill ? options.fill : "steelblue" )
    }
    else if (options.shape == "square") {
      shape = d3.select(svg).append("rect")
       .attr("x", options.x ? options.x : 100)
       .attr("y", options.y ? options.y : 50) 
       .attr("width", options.width ? options.size : 10)
       .attr("height", options.width ? options.size : 10)
       .attr("fill", options.fill ? options.fill : "orange" )  
    }
    else {
      let x = options.x ? options.x : 150, y = options.y ? options.y : 50;
      shape = d3.select(svg).append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolStar).size(options.size ? options.size : 100))
        .attr("transform","translate("+[x,y]+")")
        .attr("fill", options.fill ? options.fill : "crimson")
  
    }
  
  return shape.node();
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is the perfect situation for using a [detached element](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#create). You could also use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), but a detached element is more idiomatic in a D3 code.

For creating the detached `whatever` SVG element all you need is:

```
var detached = d3.create('svg:whatever');
```

According to the documentation,

> Given the specified element name, returns a single-element selection containing a detached element of the given name in the current document.

This is very similar to [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51431803/5768908), because internally `d3.create` uses `document.createElement`. But pay attention, it uses `document.createElement`, not `document.createElementNS`, so the namespace is necessary here:

```
var detached = d3.create('svg:whatever');
//this is the namespace----ˆ
```

Then, after that, you can create the structure you want. For instance:

```
detached.selectAll(null)
    .data(d3.range(5))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    //etc...
```

Finally,get the node of the detached element and append it wherever you want, using `append`:

```
svg.append(function(){ return detached.node();});
```

Here is a demo, the function `makeGraphic` creates a detached element, and returns its node. Then, we just append the returned value to the SVG:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 300);

function makeGraphic() {
  var detached = d3.create('svg:g');
  detached.selectAll(null)
    .data(d3.range(10))
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function() {
      return Math.random() * 500
    })
    .attr("cy", function() {
      return Math.random() * 300
    })
    .attr("r", function() {
      return Math.random() * 50
    })
    .attr("fill", function(_, i) {
      return d3.schemeCategory10[i]
    });
  return detached.node();
};

svg.append(makeGraphic)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice answer, didn't even cross my mind to use `d3.create()` - just habit on my part I guess.

Comment: At the end it's almost the same thing that you dis with vanilla javascript.